# spi 74hc595 Cascading atmega64

Tags: arduino, spi, atmega

I have a problem with displaying 40 values displayed on the 7 segment (40 components 74hc595 cascade link.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Zq7.jpg)

I implement my program on arduino and it works well
Here is my code:

```
 static const byte Pattern[] = {
    B00010100, // 0
    B00111111, // 1
    B10011000, // 2
    B00011010, // 3
    B00110011, // 4
    B01010010, // 5     
    B01010000, // 6
    B00011111, // 7
    B00010000, // 8
    B00010010, // 9
    B00010000}; // BLANK


byte HC595_DS_POS = 2;     //Data pin (DS) pin location

byte HC595_SH_CP_POS = 3;  //Shift Clock (SH_CP) pin location
byte HC595_ST_CP_POS = 4;  //Store Clock (ST_CP) pin location



void IE74595_Out(uint8_t *p, unsigned char n)
{
  unsigned char i, j;
  uint8_t b;


  digitalWrite(HC595_ST_CP_POS,0);
  digitalWrite(HC595_SH_CP_POS,0);


  for(j=0;j<n;j++)
  {
    b = Pattern[*(p+n-j-1)];    // Lay byte cao nhat truoc

    for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    {

      digitalWrite(HC595_SH_CP_POS,0);

      if(b & 0b00000001)
      {

       digitalWrite(HC595_DS_POS,1);

      }
      else
      {

        digitalWrite(HC595_DS_POS,0);

      }

      digitalWrite(HC595_SH_CP_POS,1);

      b=b>>1;  //Now bring next bit at MSB position

    }
  }


digitalWrite(HC595_ST_CP_POS,1);

}



void setup()
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(HC595_ST_CP_POS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(HC595_SH_CP_POS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(HC595_DS_POS, OUTPUT); 

}

void loop() {

   uint8_t Data[40]={2,5,1,3,2,1,3,6,1,9,4,8,1,7,0,5,1,2,5,6,5,4,1,4,1,8,1,3,1,9,5,6,4,5,6,2,6,1,0,2};


          IE74595_Out(Data,40);


}
```

And then I remade another program on atmel studio and I load it via extrem burner and Usbasp in my card
Here is my code :

```
    #define F_CPU 8000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

static const uint8_t Pattern[] = {
    0b00010100, // 0
    0b00111111, // 1
    0b10011000, // 2  
    0b00011010, // 3
    0b00110011, // 4
    0b01010010, // 5  
    0b01010000, // 6  
    0b00011111, // 7
    0b00010000, // 8
    0b00010010, // 9
        0b00010000}; // BLANK

#define output_low(port,pin) port &= ~(1<<pin)
#define output_high(port,pin) port |= (1<<pin)
#define set_input(portdir,pin) portdir &= ~(1<<pin)
#define set_output(portdir,pin) portdir |= (1<<pin)

#define HC595_DS_POS PC4    //Data pin (DS) pin location
#define HC595_SH_CP_POS PC5  //Shift Clock (SH_CP) pin location
#define HC595_ST_CP_POS PC6  //Store Clock (ST_CP) pin location



#define HC595_PORT   PORTC
#define HC595_DDR    DDRC


void IE74595_Out(uint8_t *p, unsigned char n)
{
    unsigned char i, j;
    uint8_t b;

    output_low(HC595_PORT,HC595_ST_CP_POS);
     output_low(HC595_PORT,HC595_SH_CP_POS);


    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        b = Pattern[*(p+n-j-1)];// Lay byte cao nhat truoc


        for(i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            output_low(HC595_PORT,HC595_SH_CP_POS);

            if(b & 0b00000001)
            {

                output_high(HC595_PORT,HC595_DS_POS);

            }
            else
            {

                output_low(HC595_PORT,HC595_DS_POS);

            }

            output_high(HC595_PORT,HC595_SH_CP_POS);
            b=b>>1;  

        }
    }


    output_high(HC595_PORT,HC595_ST_CP_POS);
}

int main(void)
{
     set_output(DDRC,HC595_DS_POS);
    set_output(DDRC,HC595_SH_CP_POS); 
    set_output(DDRC,HC595_ST_CP_POS);

    uint8_t Data[40]={5,9,1,6,1,1,0,9,1,7,1,5,4,2,6,2,8,7,0,7,1,2,3,5,1,5,4,2,1,7,5,9,1,9,4,8,1,5,2,9};


 while (1)
 {


    IE74595_Out(Data,40);
        return 1;


 }


}
```

Here is my card 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2pcl.jpg)

The display is not like that of the arduino
I only have the last value displayed

I have developed my electronic card in china.

Is the problem of the material ???

The only difference between the two programs is:
DigitalWrite () on arduino
And Output_High () or output_Low on atmel

Is the implementation of DigitalWrite == Output_high() or output_Low()  ????

Must i Write the last instruction Return 1; after the while ????

Thank's

Comment: Do you have proper decoupling capacitor for each shift register? Also `digitalWrite` is about 80 times slower than `sbi`/`cbi` instructions, so missing decoupling might be an issue. Especially for such currents (half of all segments On @20mA => 3.2A and all segments On => 6.4A).

Comment: no i use electronic card that i developped in china

Comment: I find the solution

Comment: i find the solution I add a delay before Clock

Comment: and it's ok  here you are the code

Comment: _delay_us(50);
   output_high(HC595_PORT,HC595_SH_CP_POS);b=b>>1;

Answer (score -1):

The 10K pull-down resistor on the SS (Slave Select) is designed to keep the registers from clocking in bits while the main processor is booting, and the SS line might be "floating" and in an indeterminate state.

Here is [the date sheet of 74hc595](http://www.componentschip.com/details/Texas-Instruments/74HC595D.html)

The call to SPI.transfer() sends a byte to the register (a bit at a time) and then bringing the LATCH (otherwise known as SS or ST) line high causes the data to be transferred from the register's internal memory to the output pins.

Pin connections

Pin connections for Uno and similar: